# Display location service alert on top of all views

Tags: objective-c, location, mbprogresshud

My app start by loading files at the splash image with `progressHUD` window.
In `appDelegate` i check if the location service in on,if its ON so no problem,after finish loading, the `progressHUD` disappear,but if the user getting alert that request permission for location services it's appears behind the `progressHUD` windows and i cant cancel/ok it while the app is loading.

How can i show this alert always on top of all other views,specially at begging on top of splash `progressHUD`?

Comment: What, if any, setting of `windowLevel` are you giving to your `progressHUD` window?

Answer (score 0):

Which HUD control are you using?

I am personally using `SVProgressHUD` which is really cool and complete… but has one single drawback: it creates its own `UIWindow` to display the HUD on top over everything. This behavior is not recommended by Apple and does not work, as you just realized, when the system creates its own `UIWindows` especially to display `UIAlertViews`.

The solution I used is to modify `SVProgressHUD` to add itself on top of the application's `window.rootViewController.view`, so that it stays on top of everything… in its own main window, letting stuff like `UIAlertViews` being displayed on their private window that is on top of this one, and thus letting you interact with `UIAlertViews`even when your progressHUD is visible.

---

*(If you are not using `SVProgressHUD`, the another class you use probably does have the same issue, so check with that one)*

I should have posted a pull request to `SVProgressHUD` but didn't have the time yet. Will probably do anytime soon if I don't forget ;)

Comment: I'm using the basic `MBProgressHUD`. Didn't understood how exactly you modify it so`UIAlertViews` being displayed? Basically i need it only for one alert-`location service`, cant I some how to control this specific alert?

Comment: No you can't control on which window `UIAlertViews` are displayed (and certainly not `UIAlertView` displayed by the OS itself as the one used by the location service). I don't use `MBProgressHUD` but if it has the same behavior and issue as the one I explained, using its own window on top of everything, even system alert views, then you'll need your progress HUD to be displayed in your main view directly instead of a separate window (I don't really use MBProgressHUD so you'll have to check in the code or contact the developer about this).